# Django model field unique among all subclasses

Tags: django, inheritance, models

I have the following model structure:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class B(A):
    ctx_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=1)

class C(A):
    ctx_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=2)
```

I want to make sure that the `ctx_order` field is unique among all subclasses that inherit from `A`. Is there a way to accomplish that or would I have to do the validation myself?

Comment: do you mean all values or default only? and `blank=False, null=False` is default so you can remove it.

Comment: The `ctx_order` field should always be unique among all subclasses